# How to manually set createdAt timestamp in mongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to migrate my DB by adding timestamps to all the rows which were missing timestamps earlier. I have calculated createdAt timestamp using _id but I'm not able to set the timestamp. What am I doing wrong here?
Can someone help?

```
    let Question = db.model('Question');

    let items = await Question.findWithDeleted();

    let processedIds = items.map((q) => q._id);
    processedIds.forEach(function (id) {

        const timestamp = id.getTimestamp();

        // const date = new Date(parseInt(timestamp, 16) * 1000);
        // echo(timestamp)
        Question.update({ "_id": id }, { "$set": { createdAt: timestamp } }, (h) => {
            console.log(h);
        });

    });
```

Here is the model:

```
    const Question = new Schema({
        "type": {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            enum: Object.values(questionTypes),
            required: 'Question type is required'
        },
        "text": {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        "desc": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "options": [{
            "id": ObjectId,
            "name": NotRequiredStringSchema,
            "helperText": NotRequiredStringSchema,
            "icon_key": NotRequiredStringSchema,
            "icon_url": NotRequiredStringSchema,
            "icon_svg": NotRequiredStringSchema
        }],
        "placeHolder": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "buttonPosition": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "buttonText": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "buttonHoverText": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "helperText": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "max": Number,
        "min": Number,
        "default": Mixed,
        "icon_key": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "icon_url": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "icon_svg": NotRequiredStringSchema,
        "showTick": { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
        "lang": {
            required: true,
            type: Map,
            of: {
                type: Map,
                of: String
            }
        }
    }, {
            timestamps: true
        });
```

Comment: can you post the schema

Comment: Can you check now @KalanaDemel?

Comment: Do you want to add timestamps on existing records or new created or updated records.

Comment: @Abhinav Jain, check if the solution helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make you schema like this

```
const SchemaName = new Schema({
 .......
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

It will create createdAt and updatedAt field automatically and also update their values on every time on performing create and update operation.

Now other cases if you create manually createdAt and updatedAt fields like this schema

```
const SchemaName = new Schema({
 .......
 createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

Then you can use [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for update createdAt and updatedAt value on creating and updating Records.

```
SchemaName.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
});

SchemaName.pre('update', () => {
  this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your schema does not contain **createdAt** field, mongoose by default saves data with the strict option enabled where if your schema does not contain a field you cannot add a new one to it [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict). Therefore you first need to add the **createdAt** field to your schema, following is just an example.

```
 createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

After adding this as a field your query should work without issues.

Comment: I have timestamps: true so it has those fields right?
And the solution didn't work

Comment: Oh did not see the flag, but great that it worked for you :D